# SQL Server: Optimal performance clustered indexing and expected indexsize

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, indexing, sql-server-2014

I am implementing a new protocol (from 2010) for my work in SQL Server 2014 and I need to construct the ideal database structure for researchers.

**Setup**

- 17 million rows/day ~ 2 GB raw data ~ 520 GB/year
- 22 columns
- Expected to have super-fast queries on all columns
- Most frequent query will be something along the lines of

  ```
  select something, date, product 
  from mytable
  where product = '45' and date between '20100811' and '20140811'
  ```

**Table** structure:

```
Date     | Product | Time          | something | something | something | something
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
20140811 | 45      | "14:55:46:13" |
```

My table has a unique combination when using Date and Time.

**Question**

Would the query benefit from having the dates on separate tables instead of in a HUGE table? i.e. perform a join operation on the dates asked for.

Is it right to use clustered index on date and time? If so, how should i make my non-clustered so that this becomes optimal?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Will the results need to be up-to-the-second accurate, or is this more of a data warehouse solution?  You didn't indicate your SQL Server version, but can you work with [columnstore indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088.aspx)?

Comment: haven't seen the [columnstore indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088.aspx) solution in anywhere. @Dave.Gugg That seems interesting as I will have multiple values in each of the columns.

Comment: Thank you @Dave.Gugg we have now started using columnstore indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it right to use clustered index on date and time?

That's not exactly unusual, especially if the vast majority of your queries are going to be filtered by date and you have a lot of ad hoc queries.

That said, I generally just go with indexing on the primary key. Assuming, of course, the primary key is an Identity or Sequence and not a random GUID.

> Most frequent query will be something along the lines of

For that particular query you want your non-clustered index to be on Product first, then Date. This will allow you to home in on exactly the right rows (Index Seek). If you do Date then Product it has to scan all of the records within the date range (Index Scan). The product part of the index won't actually have an effect because very few records will have the same date.

When in doubt, write out a few dozen rows of data as a tree. Then pretend you are a computer and look for the data. If you find it tedious to go down each and every branch looking for possible matches, so will your database server. But if you can go directly down the tree to the first row, walk sideways picking up good rows and not needing to skip bad ones, then you've got a good index.

> Expected to have super-fast queries on all columns

Not going to happen. Clustered columnstore may give you decent queries on all columns (assuming you aren't doing something stupid like SELECT *), but for 'super-fast' you need covering indexes. And there is no way you can create a covering index for every possible query.

Answer (score 1):

With 17 millions/day we're talking about one entry every 5 milliseconds (assuming inserts are evenly distributed). If you want to use Date and Time as your clustered index you'll need to make sure there are no duplicates when you try to insert data. It's not impossible ta achieve, but it's not easy either (especially with such an insert frequency).

You'll definitely want to use TIME(7) as the data type to be able to get the slightest time difference to insert your data.

Other than that, making Date and Time column the clustered index sounds like a good plan. The index size is even one byte less than a Numeric(18,0) and is equal to bigint.

As a non-clustered index I'd use Product, Date, Time INCLUDE(something).

You may have noticed I recommended Date and Time data type. I strongly vote against storing the data in character format.
Reason 1: a string like '20149999' is valid but is not a valid date, same for '37:71:80:ab' and Time...
Reason 2: The storage size is smaller if you're using the appropriate data format hence the index becomes more narrow, too.

Comment: +1 for recommending the **appropriate** data types instead of just switching to `varchar` !

Comment: Clustered indexes don't have to be unique. That's what the primary key is for. (Though the primary key is the clustered index by default.)